# How to get non arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**I have this Array:**

```
[["18.20"], ["89.90"], {Fungi: "5", Salami: "5"}]
```

Now I want to access Fungi and Salami in my for loop.

How can I achieve this?

**This is my code:**

```
for(i = 0; i < values2.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    $(".list-group").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" +  + "<span class='badge'>" + values2[i] +"</span></li>");
}
```

`values2` returns the array from above. 
`values2[i]` returns the content in the arrays inside the array.

This should be like so, but now I want to access the non-arrays inside the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes it is...

Comment: You cannot intermix arrays and hashes like this in JavaScript.  You could do something like this, though: `[["18.20"], ["89.90"], {Fungi: "5"}, {Salami: "5"}]`.

Comment: Redo your aray as `[["18.20"], ["89.90"], { Fungi: "5" }, { Salami: "5" }]`

Comment: + keep in mind that mixing data types inside an array is **not** a good practice

Comment: Sorry, i just copied from chrome.

Comment: @Alnitak I think you missed what the author had originally posted.  This is not executable in JavaScript: `[["18.20"], ["89.90"], Fungi: "5", Salami: "5"]`.

Comment: @kevin628 ah, I was looking at the current contents of the post - didn't see the older (invalid) version

Answer (score 3):

Could you not loop through the array and return the non array inside?

```
var data = [["18.20"], ["89.90"], {Fungi: "5", Salami: "5"}];

data.forEach(d => {
  if(!Array.isArray(d)){
    console.log(d)
  }
});
```

https://repl.it/EtZi/0

**EDIT:**

Remember this:

```
console.log(typeof [] === 'object') // true
console.log(typeof {} === 'object') // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the index and the property for access.

You can use the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like

> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

```js
var array = [["18.20"], ["89.90"], { Fungi: "5", Salami: "5" }];

console.log(array[2].Fungi);
```

For unknown items, you could iterate and seach for an object with the wanted key. Process the result and exit the loop.

```js
var array = [["18.20"], ["89.90"], { Fungi: "5", Salami: "5" }];

array.some(function getProperty(key) {
    return function (a) {
        if (a && typeof a === 'object' && key in a) {
            console.log(a[key]);
            return true;
        }
    };
}('Fungi'));
```

Comment: This is assuming you know the location of the non-array though.

Comment: with mixed structures, you should know where you object is located. with random sorted arrays, then you need to iterate and search for the property you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added the Fungi/Salami part later to an actual array, it should look like this now:

`{0: [0: "18.20"], 1: [0: "89.90"], 2: {"Fungi": "5", "Salami": "5"}}`

Also assuming the object is stored in the variable `data`:

You should use the index, and then the `.` to access members like so:

`data[2].Fungi` should return 5

Answer (score -4):

It looks like you intended to use a JavaScript Object, rather than an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

`var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

`var myHonda = {color: "red", wheels: 4, engine: {cylinders: 4, size: 2.2}};`

Comment: Everything in javascript is an object.